# undefined method `prev' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined

### _form

```
<%= link_to 'Previous Post', blog_path(@post).previous if @post.previous %>
<%= link_to 'Next Post', blog_path(@post).next if @post.next %>
```

I'm so confused here, guys. `next` works, but `previous` gives me the error `undefined method 'previous' for "/blog/4":String`

### post.rb

```
  def next
    Post.where("id > ?", id).first
  end

  def previous
    Post.where("id < ?", id).last
  end
```

If I switch the word `previous` to `last` then the error goes away, but instead of linking to the previous post it links to the current post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `previous` and `next` on the `blog_path` method, which returns just a plain `String`.

You need to make sure to call it on `@post`:

```
blog_path(@post.previous)
```

Comment: Thank you! Weird that it worked for next tho and not previous. I'll checkmark your answer in 6 minutes when SO lets me :)

Comment: You're welcome! `String` in fact defines a method called `next`. For `"/blog/4"` it would return `"/blog/5"`. It also defines `last`, which would return `"4"`. That would explain why the other options did succeed :)